# Documents required for a Mexican citizen getting married to a Pakistani in Dubai?

Tags: dubai, uae, mexican-citizens

Which documents are needed for getting married in Dubai to a Mexican woman? She will come on a visitors' visa and she will come between 5 to 10 days.

I have resident visa and I am from Pakistan. What documents are needed from her?

Comment: Normally a visitor visa is not valid for weddings, and you should research the documents you need for Pakistan and from Mexico to validate the Dubai wedding.

Comment: This is not off-topic. Getting married abroad during a temporary stay is on-topic for the site.

Comment: I hope I don't have to ask this question, but you have met your future bride in person haven't you? If you haven't then I would like to (gently) point out that there are many instances of online dating fraud.  I don't want to imply that this is your case,  but without knowing more your situation does raise some red flags for me.

Answer (score 4):

According to UAE law only one party must have a residence visa, and both must pass a medical examination.  They also state that "Non-Muslims can conclude marriage formalities at: the embassy or consulate of their country in the UAE or at a temple or a church as per their religion." Sharia marriage laws will apply if the both the bride and groom are Muslim, or if the groom is a Muslim and the bride is Christian.  You should each check with your respective countries of citizenship as to how to register a marriage that occurs abroad.

More here: https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/social-affairs/marriage