# Documents required for a mexican citizen getting married to Sri Lankan in Dubai

Tags: dubai, uae, weddings, mexican-citizens

Which documents are needed for getting married in Dubai to a Mexican woman? She will come on a visitors' visa and she will come between 5 to 10 days.

I have resident visa and I am from Sri Lanka . What documents are needed from her?
And how can find a any marriage service consultant?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done so far? Eg https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/social-affairs/marriage

Comment: I assume you know this person in real life? Sorry to ask, but there are a lot of romance scams out there and sometimes they get as far as trying to convince the mark to send money for a supposed visa or plane ticket for marriage.

Comment: Same you, different bride? [Documents required for a Mexican citizen getting married to a Pakistani in Dubai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148875/documents-required-for-a-mexican-citizen-getting-married-to-a-pakistani-in-dubai)